# how to communicate between two composites in swt

Tags: java, swt

I'm building an application in SWT that contains two composites, and I need to communicate between them..

In other words, when i click in one button inside composite "A" i need update table in composite "B" or get the elements of that table!

I have two sugestions, but i don't know if they are the better way...

1. Pass base class to composites, and commucicate between parent;
2. composites extends base class and call for example "parent.updateTableOfCompositeB()"

I build this simple example for a better compreention of question..

my base class:

```
public class Test {
    protected Shell shell;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Test window = new Test();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setSize(450, 300);
        shell.setText("SWT Application");
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        Composite butComposite = new buttonsComp(shell, SWT.NONE);
        Composite tableComposite = new TableComp(shell, SWT.NONE);
    }
}
```

my buttons composite:

```
public class buttonsComp extends Composite {
    public buttonsComp(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
        Button btnNewButton = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton.setText("New Button");
        Button btnAsd = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        btnAsd.setText("asd");
    }
    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
    }
}
```

my table composite

```
public class TableComp extends Composite {
    private Table table;

    public TableComp(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        table = new Table(this, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        TableColumn tblclmnColumn = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        tblclmnColumn.setWidth(100);
        tblclmnColumn.setText("column1");
    }
    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
    }
    public void updateTable(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            TableItem item = new TableItem(table, i);
            item.setText("bla" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

what is the better way?

sorry my english..
Regards 
Alexandre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with an event design where your composites are either Listeners, Handlers or both, depending on who must get the information.

http://www.marco.panizza.name/dispenseTM/slides/exerc/eventNotifier/eventNotifier.html

Let's go with the simplistic aproach even though a mediator may help in your case.

First you'll need an Event. Also, in this case, let's say you want to send a message inside the event. You can, offcourse, add any fields that you find you may need in your implementation.

```
import java.util.EventObject;

public class SomethingHappenedEvent extends EventObject{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String message;

    public SomethingHappenedEvent(Object source, String message) {
        super(source);
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Then you'll need a event listener. This will be an interface that you will later implement on each class that needs to be notified.

```
import java.util.EventListener;

public interface SomethingHappenedListener extends EventListener {

    public void somethingHappened(SomethingHappenedEvent e);
}
```

Next you need to handle those events and also be able to send them to their correct listeners. Let's consider again the simplest case where you send your event to every listener registered in your handler.

For this example I'm going to use your TableComp class.

```
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

public class TableComp extends Composite {
    private Table table;

    //Event listener list ===================================
    private EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();

    public TableComp(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        table = new Table(this, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        TableColumn tblclmnColumn = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
        tblclmnColumn.setWidth(100);
        tblclmnColumn.setText("column1");
    }
    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
    }
    public void updateTable(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            TableItem item = new TableItem(table, i);
            item.setText("bla" + i);
        }
        //===================TABLE WAS UPDATED. FIRE EVENT ==================
        fireEvent(new SomethingHappenedEvent("foo"));
    }

    /*
     * ========== Event Handling ==========
     */
    public void addMessageListener(SomethingHappenedListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(SomethingHappenedListener.class, listener);
    }
    public void removeMessageListener(SomethingHappenedListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(SomethingHappenedListener.class, listener);
    }
    public void fireEvent(SomethingHappenedEvent evt) {
        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i = i+2) {
            if (listeners[i] == SomethingHappenedListener.class) {
                ((SomethingHappenedListener) listeners[i+1]).somethingHappened(evt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I am only firing the event to the type of listeners I want, in this the SomethingHappenedListener type. This behaviour can be altered for your own purposes.

Now let's say you want to treat the event in the button class. just implement the listener and it's done.

```
public class buttonsComp extends Composite implements SomethingHappenedListener{

    public buttonsComp(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
        Button btnNewButton = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton.setText("New Button");
        Button btnAsd = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
        btnAsd.setText("asd");
    }

    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {

    }

    public void somethingHappened(SomethingHappenedEvent e)
    {
        //do stuff....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding listeners to the swt widgets is perhaps the right way to go. You could do something on the lines shown in the below code snippet.

```
Button button =  new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
Table table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
..
..
//register listener for the selection event on the button
button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Listener Called!");
        table.getItems();  //or do what you want with the table.
    }
});
```